# Event stream disk size

Tags: projection, event-driven, event-driven-design, event-stream, event-stream-processing

I have event store in postgres connected to RabbitMQ event stream. Since we have limited disk space on the Rabbit side and too many events we can't keep all events in the event stream forever rather we must configure retention policy.

If I want to replay that event store to stream to be able to rebuild projection, and stream does not have enough disk space to support all of those events how can I do this? Are you familiar with some patterns for this problem in Event Driven Architecture?